# Laravel 8 route model binding not return ant record?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, route-model-binding

I am using below code for route model binding but the binding variable does not return any value.
MY ROUTE

```
Route::resource('offertypes', 'OfferTYpeController');
```

CONTROLLER CODE

```
    public function edit(OfferType $offerType)
    {
        dd($offerType);
        return view('admin.offer-types._form', compact('offerType'));
    }
```

BLADE FILE CODE

```
<td>
 <a href="{{ route('admin.offertypes.edit', $offerType->id) }}">{{ ucwords($offerType->title) }}</a>
</td>
```

RETURN VALUE
[image: my code returns this]

Comment: how do you call `edit` function and data of request !?

Comment: show your route

Comment: BLADE FILE CODE 
<a href="{{ route('admin.offertypes.edit', $offerType->id) }}">{{ ucwords($offerType->title) }}</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use similar route parameter as your variable

Means your route should look like this

```php
Route::get('edit/{offerType}', [SomeController::class, 'edit']);
```

Note: `offerType` is exactly same typed in parameter and in method variable.

Another issue could be if you have mistakenly commented this middleware in `app\Http\Kernel.php`

[image]

Comment: Route Code 
```
 Route::resource('offertypes', 'OfferTYpeController');
```

Comment: check your route list in terminal using command `php artisan route:list` and see what parameter is being used in `offertypes` routes

Comment: |        | GET|HEAD  | admin/offertypes/{offertype}/edit         | admin.offertypes.edit             | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\OfferTYpeController@edit                    | web           |

Comment: @GaganSharma offertype is all lower case in routelist ? if yes, then you also need to make it lowercase in your edit() method, also check my updated answer

Comment: Note: offerType is exactly same typed in parameter and in method variable. (my issue solve by this)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359111/how-i-use-this-chat-functionality-in-codeigniter.....